# Flutter - SingleChildScrollView not scroll to the bottom of the column with keyboard on

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used SingleChildScrollView in many places of my app and everything is fine. However, it cannot scroll to the bottom of the column when the keyboard pops up in the scenario below.

```dart
Future<void> _showCupertinoModalBottomSheet() async {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    await showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: screenSize.height * 0.8,
            color: CupertinoColors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CupertinoTextField(
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //List of widgets
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

I have no idea why it is scrollable but cannot scroll to the bottom, and some contents are hidden by the keyboard.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case I changed `Stateless widget` to `Stateful` and the problem is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a padding widget works

```
Future<void> _showCupertinoModalBottomSheet() async {
  final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  await showCupertinoModalPopup(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: screenSize.height * 0.8,
          color: CupertinoColors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CupertinoTextField(),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) Text(i.toString())
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Child of Expanded should be one of (Row, Column, or Flex) only, ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 2):

As a last resort, maybe try adding a `SizedBox` widget as the last child of your `SingleChildScrollView`. Alternatively, you could wrap it in `Padding`. Either way, set the `top` `padding` parameter or `height` parameter of the `SizedBox` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / x`. X being an adjustable value that you can mess around with to try to get the percentage of the height of screen it isn't scrolling down to. This will push everything else up a certain amount.

Again, this is 'hacky', so use it only if you can't find another solution.

Also maybe try setting these in your `Scaffold`, they may help:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Also changing your `stateless` widget into a `stateful` widget sometimes helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately the first two solutions don't work in my case and I'm already using a stateful widget. May I ask why this problem occurs? Does it have anything to do with CupertinoModalPopup?

Comment: @CassieLiu I believe it's because of some wacky box constraints, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed mine:

I wrapped my widgets with a SingleChildScrollView and removed the resizeToAvoidBottomInset property from the Scaffold.